# Validar datos por GET con PHP

Tags: php

Quizás esto sea algo simple, pero no puedo resolverlo. Estoy pasando datos por `GET` pero si quiero pasar un dato que no existe tengo este error: `Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool`.

Es un sistema de tickets que se genera una vez realizado el pago. Paso ese numero por `GET` y veo si ese ticket ya fue utilizado, pero me olvide de ver si existe.

```
// Dato que viene por URL
http://localhost/abanda/?page=ticket&number=TCK-162706000

----

// Dato que tomo
$codde = $_GET['number'];
if(!$codde){
    echo 'El ticket no existe';
}

$row = $abanda->getticket($codde);
$estado = $row['estado'];
if($estado == 0){
    // Formulario
    // Ingresa la fecha de reserva
} else {
    // El ticket ya fue utilizado
}
```

El problema es que cuando paso un valor que no existe: `TCK-000000000`, me sale el error que mencioné arriba y me muestra el formulario, algo que debería pasar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes hacer una tercera validación para determinar si el estado llega vacío o nulo *(booleano false)*...

Lo puedes chequear con la función `empty`, la cual valida si una variable está vacía o nula. [Acá encuentras la documentación oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

```
if(empty($estado)){
    //El ticket no existe
} else if($estado == 0){
    // Formulario
    // Ingresa la fecha de reserva
} else {
    // El ticket ya fue utilizado
}
```

Comment: Había utilizado `isset()` pero no se me ocurrió hacer uso de `empty`. Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Hice algunas correcciones

```
//Validamos si el parámetro está definido con la función isset()
//Si no lo está agregado un valor vacío
$codde = (isset($_GET['number']))?$_GET['number']:'';

//Si el parámetro "number" no viene por URL
if(empty($codde))
    echo 'El ticket no existe';


$row = $abanda->getticket($codde);

//Valido igualmente el acceso del arreglo para comprobar si está definido para el valor especificado
//Si lo está adicionalmente se hace la comparación
if(isset($row['estado']) && $row['estado'] == 0){
    // Formulario
    // Ingresa la fecha de reserva
} else {
    // El ticket ya fue utilizado
}
```

Comment: Bienvenid@ a [es.so], te recomiendo leer [answer] para de detalles tu respuesta o agregues contexto más amplio del código que agregas.